# Canonical URLs for anchor / jump links?

Tags: html, hyperlink, seo, anchor, canonical-link

When using 'Jump to' aka 'Anchor' links to jump to a different part of a webpage should I use canonical URL or a 'no-follow' link for the purposes of SEO? Does it even matter? If so, which is better?

Basically, I don't want to have spiders look at `http://www.example.com/examplepage/` and `http://www.example.com/examplepage/#jumptolink` and index them as 'duplicate content'.

Given they have different URLs should they have different meta-descriptions and titles? Not sure.

I have checked on multiple sites, forums and blogs and this was pretty close ([Dynamic Url & Canonical meta tag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873655/dynamic-url-canonical-meta-tag-issue)) but it doesn't seem to relate to 'jump to' links.

Comment: If you use `<a href='#section'` with no complete url then http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/anchor-links.html is applicable I think.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks, that article seems to answer my question perfectly - makes sense really! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Handling of anchor links is done entirely on the client side. They are not even sent to the server. Google ignores them entirely while crawling. Google just loads the page and indexes it as if it hadn't had a anchor link in the first place.